# Universal Free Monoid: "Undo"

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, monoid

If I have some free monoid: $A^\ast$, generated from $A$.

I can define a function that undoes any application (concatenation), of a element of $A$ to an element of $A^\ast$:
$$f:\; A^\ast \to A^\ast$$

It is given by:
$\forall g\in A$, for $\forall a \in A^\ast$, and for $\epsilon$ the identity element:

$$ag \mapsto a$$
$$\epsilon \mapsto \epsilon$$

This covers all elements of $A^\ast$ because every non-identity element of a free monoid can be expressed as another element, with one of the generators applied to it.
It is a function (though showing that is a little harder)

Note that since $\epsilon g = g$
$$g \mapsto \epsilon$$

**Is there a name for $f$?**
I have been thinking of it as the *parent* function

Comment: Note that $\epsilon$ is **not** in $A$, so your justification of "$\varepsilon\mapsto\varepsilon$" is incorrect; you would have to postulate that as a second clause in the definition.

Comment: If your function was $ga \mapsto a$, then such a function is akin to the cdr function in the functional programming language Lisp.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks,. fixed. I (incorrectly) thought it was a requirement of free monoids to have the identity in the generator.

Comment: Is your map supposed to be a homomorphism? In other words, writing $\eta$ for imbedding of $A$ in $A^*$, is your map is the unique homomorphism $f:A^*\to A^*$ such that $h=f\eta$ is the map defined for each  $a \in A\setminus \{g\}$ by $h(a)=\eta(a)$ and for $g$ by $h(g)=e$?

Comment: @Nex: I'm not sure I understand.
re: _"Is your map supposed to be a homomorphism"_
No it is not supposed to be a homomorphism, and it isnot a homomorphsim
As I understand it to be a homomorphism: 
$f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$
 and that does not hold:
$f(a_{1}g_{1}\cdot a_{2}g_{2})=f(a_{1}g_{1}a_{2}g_{2})=a_{1}g_{1}a_{2}$
vs

$f(a_{1}g_{1})\cdot f(a_{2}g_{2})=a_{1}a_{2}$
 so

$a_{1}a_{2}\neq a_{1}g_{1}a_{2}$
  unless $g_{1}=\epsilon$
 , which it does not, as $g_{1}\in A$
 , $\epsilon\notin A$
 as Noah pointed out.

I am still processing the rest of you comment

Comment: Okay, I understand now (I thought $g$ was fixed). So roughly speaking it removes the last letter from a word?

Comment: Yes. if $A$ was a set of letters, it would remove the last letter from the word. ($A$ in the particular case I am thinking about is countably infinite; but I don't think that matters). $g$  is just any generator, I will edit to make clearer